# Not aable to set image from camera to imageview in android

Tags: java, android

### What i am trying to do:

I am trying to display a image captured from camera to imageview in android

### What is happening:

As soon i capture the image and set it image is not setting in the image view instead the fragment is getting destroyed

---

On click of button i am calling  `selectImage()`

---

private void selectImage() {

```
//final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

final String[] options = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_pick_list);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.str_add_photo));
builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        if (options[item].equals(getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_pick_list)[0]))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            intent.putExtra("outputFormat",
                    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

            //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
        else if (options[item].equals(getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_pick_list)[1]))
        {
            Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

        }
        else if (options[item].equals(getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_pick_list)[2])) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
builder.show();
```

}

---

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //----------------------------------SCREEN NAME-------------------------//
        ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.screenname_register));

        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                //FILE IS FROM CAMERA-----SingleIMAGE
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap=CommonFunctions.CompressImage(f);
                    if(flgProfileOrBannerPicClkd.equalsIgnoreCase("profile")){
                        profilePicImgId.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        isProfilePicAdded=true;
                        profileImgId=System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
                        profilePicImgId.setTag(profileImgId+".jpg");
                    }else if(flgProfileOrBannerPicClkd.equalsIgnoreCase("banner")){
                        portfolioPicImgId.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        isPortfolioPicAdded=true;
                        portfolioImgId=System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
                        portfolioPicImgId.setTag(portfolioImgId+".jpg");
                    }else{
                        ((ImageView)addressImageView.findViewWithTag("addrImgTag")).setBackgroundResource(0);
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(f).resize(100, 100).into(addressImageView);
                    }

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "cameraimage" + File.separator + unixTime+".jpg";

                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush(); ///////////////////////////////////////////// ----- CURSOR NOT CLOSED --- CHECK THIS IF APP CRASHES IN FUTURE
                        outFile.close();///////////////////////////////////////////// ----- CURSOR NOT CLOSED --- CHECK THIS IF APP CRASHES IN FUTURE
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

...... other code
```

**Log:**

```
01-11 23:38:38.175: W/System.err(4531): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at com.windhyaworks.fragments.FrgRegisterAsServiceProvider.onActivityResult(FrgRegisterAsServiceProvider.java:457)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:163)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5446)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3428)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2845)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
01-11 23:38:38.179: W/System.err(4531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 23:38:38.180: W/System.err(4531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-11 23:38:38.180: W/System.err(4531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-11 23:38:38.180: W/System.err(4531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-11 23:38:38.180: W/System.err(4531):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 23:38:38.256: I/Adreno-EGL(4531): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8610_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
01-11 23:38:38.256: I/Adreno-EGL(4531): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
01-11 23:38:38.256: I/Adreno-EGL(4531): Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
01-11 23:38:38.256: I/Adreno-EGL(4531): Local Branch: 
01-11 23:38:38.256: I/Adreno-EGL(4531): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
01-11 23:38:38.256: I/Adreno-EGL(4531): Local Patches: NONE
01-11 23:38:38.256: I/Adreno-EGL(4531): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
01-11 23:38:38.291: D/OpenGLRenderer(4531): Enabling debug mode 0
01-11 23:38:39.540: I/System.out(4531): {"message":"Not a Vendor","status":"False","isVendor":"False"}
01-11 23:38:39.607: I/dalvikvm(4531): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.isTransitionGroup, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.captureTransitioningViews
01-11 23:38:39.607: W/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11818: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.isTransitionGroup ()Z
01-11 23:38:39.607: D/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
01-11 23:38:39.608: I/dalvikvm(4531): Could not find method android.view.View.getTransitionName, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.findNamedViews
01-11 23:38:39.608: W/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11647: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;
01-11 23:38:39.608: D/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
01-11 23:38:39.609: I/dalvikvm(4531): Could not find method android.view.View.getTransitionName, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.getTransitionName
01-11 23:38:39.609: W/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11647: Landroid/view/View;.getTransitionName ()Ljava/lang/String;
01-11 23:38:39.609: D/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
01-11 23:38:39.610: W/dalvikvm(4531): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1; (1376)
01-11 23:38:39.610: W/dalvikvm(4531): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;' failed
01-11 23:38:39.610: E/dalvikvm(4531): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setEpicenter
01-11 23:38:39.610: W/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 370 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
01-11 23:38:39.610: D/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007
01-11 23:38:39.611: W/dalvikvm(4531): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1376)
01-11 23:38:39.611: W/dalvikvm(4531): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed
01-11 23:38:39.612: E/dalvikvm(4531): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$3', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setSharedElementEpicenter
01-11 23:38:39.612: W/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 372 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;) in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;
01-11 23:38:39.612: D/dalvikvm(4531): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0002
01-11 23:38:39.612: W/dalvikvm(4531): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1; (1376)
01-11 23:38:39.613: W/dalvikvm(4531): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$1;' failed
01-11 23:38:39.613: D/dalvikvm(4531): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x082f at 0x09 in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;.setEpicenter
01-11 23:38:39.613: W/dalvikvm(4531): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3; (1376)
01-11 23:38:39.613: W/dalvikvm(4531): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21$3;' failed
01-11 23:38:39.614: D/dalvikvm(4531): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0833 at 0x04 in Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentTransitionCompat21;.setSharedElementEpicenter
```

Comment: comment that line and then check  ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.screenname_register));

Comment: i tried .......... Still same result

Comment: does image exists check value for file in logcat (check path)